# NullPointerException in Clojure

Tags: java, sqlite, clojure

My Clojure skills are non-existant, as are my SQLite skills. For some reason I was stuck with this project at work, but I'm having a heck of a time with it.

Basically, a user submits a form and it goes to PayPal and we get it back, and we update the database that they bought something. Additionally, we also erase the temporary session out of the database that we use for their shopping cart.

My job is to add to the database the quantity of what they bought. That's my `used_quantity` below. In PHP/MySQL I would do something like:

```
update sa_forms set used_quantity = used_quantity + {quantity} where id = {id} LIMIT 1
```

but it seems like I actually have to do two steps to add to the quantity.

The only thing I addedwas the `let` statement. Without it, this whole thing works fine. With it, it breaks.

```
insert-db-order (if (:login session)
    (doseq [order db-orders]
        (j/insert! SQLDB :sa_orders
            {:form_id (:form_id order)
             :user_id (:user_id order)
             :form_name (:form_name order)
             :user_name username
             :total_cost_paid (* (:payment_amt order) (:quantity order))
             :date_completed (.getTime (java.util.Date.))
             :order_content (:html order)
             :created_at (.getTime (java.util.Date.))
             :updated_at (.getTime (java.util.Date.))
             :status false
             :quantity (:quantity order)})
         (let [quantityOf (j/query SQLDB ["SELECT used_quantity FROM sa_forms WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1" (:form_id order)])]
              (j/update! SQLDB :sa_forms
              {:used_quantity (+ (:used_quantity quantityOf) (:quantity order))}
              (sql/where  {:id  (:form_id order)}))
          )
       )
       (doseq [id (keys session-orders)]
          (j/insert! SQLDB :sa_orders
              {:form_id (:form_id (id session-orders))
               :user_id anonymous-key
               :form_name (:form_name (id session-orders))
               :user_name username
               :total_cost_paid (* (:payment_amt (id session-orders)) (:quantity (id session-orders)))
               :date_completed (.getTime (java.util.Date.))
               :order_content (:html (id session-orders))
               :created_at (.getTime (java.util.Date.))
               :updated_at (.getTime (java.util.Date.))
               :status false
               :quantity (:quantity (id session-orders))}))
           )
```

I have been getting errors all day, and I've tried multiple things. Like, for example:

```
{:used_quantity (+ (int(:used_quantity quantityOf)) (:quantity order))}
```

Because it said a map cannot be an number.
I've tried

```
{:used_quantity (+ (quantityOf) (:quantity order))}
```

Thinking because I'm only selecting one value, I don't need to show what I'm referencing.
I've also tried to `pprint` the value, or the key, or all of it, and it's all either came up as `nil` or nothing, which wasn't helpful.

In this ordeal, I learned I have to put variable definers inside of a `let` statement though, among other things, but I've spent 9 and a half hours on this and I've moved from getting one error to the next.

Can somebody offer me some clojure? In layman's terms preferably. I'm still trying to grasp the jargon of this language, and the odd syntax...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent it to my coworker who has worked with Clojure before and he fixed it after a few hours. I'm not sure if this will help anyone, but he did this:

```
(doseq [order db-orders]
    (do 
     (j/execute! SQLDB "UPDATE sa_forms SET used_quantity = used_quantity + " (:quantity order) " WHERE ? LIMIT 1" (:form_id order));
    )
   )
```

I've minimized my solution so there isn't a bunch of unneeded mark-up, but basically he added a `do` statement inside the `doseq` and we just wrote the SQL statement normally instead of using Clojure.

Like I said, I doubt this will help anyone, but there's the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, check the type of the values you are using in the context where you are getting exceptions.

```lisp
user> (type '({:quantity 1}))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user> (type {:quantity 1})
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
```

`sql/query` should be returning a sequential datatype, even if you set a limit of 1. A keyword used as a function with a seq as an argument will give a nil result:

```lisp
user> (:quantity '({:quantity 1}))
nil
```

wrapping in parens, as you also tried, is also guaranteed to be an error

```lisp
user> ('({:quantity 1}))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/eval8554/fn--8555 (form-init7057475948894346608.clj:1)
```

The way to get your result should look more like this:

```lisp
user> (+ (:quantity (first '({:quantity 1}))) 2)
3
```

Comment: also, the clojure syntax highlighting for single quotes is totally broken

Comment: No, it's not broken per se. Choice of syntax highlighting scheme is based on tags. Since there are several tags, SO chooses most popular (well, I think so), and it's not Clojure ;-) I've fixed highlighting in your code, see the markdown for details.